# R function to find weighted frequency of elements for Random Forest trees

Tags: frequency, weighted

What Ive done: A good rule of thumb for finding potential interactions is to look for close variable splitting high in the tree i.e. near the root node. Given this, I used the getTree to extract splitting variables on the nodes and removed terminal nodes. I used MaxNuMREV to rotate the value to its maximum i.e (13 is changed to 31). Using the double lapply, I traverse all the trees and obtain the feature interactions. I apply row weights starting from 1 to ~0.06 for the lower "more random" part of the tree.

Problem: I have used multiple weighted frequency methods and none work. I need to get the weighted frequency value to judge interaction importance. For example, feature interaction 31 could have a weighted determined by each instances row location.

```
library(dplyr); library(RandomForest)
Ntrees=500
RRFModel<- randomForest(Ozone ~ ., data=airquality, mtry=3,importance=TRUE, na.action=na.omit, ntrees=Ntrees)

MaxNuMREV=function(x){  reverse_int <- function(n) {
                                   t1 <- floor(log10(n)); t2 <- 0
                                   for (i in t1:1) {t2 <- t2 + floor(n/10^i) * 10^(t1-i)}
                                   return(n*10^t1 - 99*t2)}
                         return(max(x,reverse_int(x)))
                     }

SplitVar=lapply(1:Ntrees, function(i){getTree(RRFModel, k=i, labelVar=FALSE)[,"split var"]}) 
MinLen=min(unlist(lapply(1:Ntrees,function(i){length(SplitVar[[i]][(SplitVar[[i]])!=0])})))
RowWeight=exp(-0.1*c(1:(MinLen-1)))
DoubleLL=lapply(1:Ntrees, function(j){
                            VV=matrix(lapply(1:(MinLen-1),function(i){ UU=SplitVar[[j]][(SplitVar[[j]])!=0][(i):(i+1)]
                              if(sd(unlist(UU))==0){UU=0
                              } else {UU=MaxNuMREV(as.numeric(paste0(UU,collapse="")))}
                            return((UU))}))
                            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I figured out how to make it work. This is probably not the most efficient way but it works. Im keeping on here in case someone else needs it.

```
SplitVar=lapply(1:Ntrees, function(i){getTree(RRFModel, k=i, labelVar=FALSE)[,"split var"]})
MaxNuMREV=function(x){  reverse_int <- function(n) {
                                   t1 <- floor(log10(n)); t2 <- 0
                                   for (i in t1:1) {t2 <- t2 + floor(n/10^i) * 10^(t1-i)} 
                                   return(n*10^t1 - 99*t2)}
                        return(max(x,reverse_int(x)))
                       }

 MinLen=min(unlist(lapply(1:Ntrees,function(i){length(SplitVar[[i]][(SplitVar[[i]])!=0])})))
 RowWeight=exp(-0.1*c(1:(MinLen-1)))
 DoubleLL=lapply(1:Ntrees, function(j){
                 VV=matrix(lapply(1:(MinLen-1),function(i){ UU=SplitVar[[j]][(SplitVar[[j]])!=0][(i):(i+1)]
                              if(sd(unlist(UU))==0){UU=0
                              } else {UU=MaxNuMREV(as.numeric(paste0(UU,collapse="")))}
                           return(UU)}))
                  WW=data.frame(unlist(VV),RowWeight);colnames(WW)=c("var", "wt")
                  return(WW[WW[,1]!=0,])      })

 FULLRbind=do.call("rbind",DoubleLL)
 AGGR=aggregate(FULLRbind[,"wt"], by=list(Category=FULLRbind[,"var"]), FUN=sum)
 AGGR=AGGR[order(AGGR[,"x"],decreasing=TRUE),]
```